# Is there a size limit to redis sorted set scores?

Tags: redis

I'm adding values to my sorted set where the score could be as big as 38 digits, for example 5.5857766150356906e+37. From my tests it seems like redis can handle commands like `zrangebyscore` fine with them, but I still feel like I need to ask - is there a limit to how big these scores can be?

Am I doing something way too expensive for day-to-day redis when I start storing more values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/zadd), a sorted set score is:

> the string representation of a double precision floating point number.

A [double-precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

> allows the representation of numbers between 10<sup>−308</sup> and 10<sup>308</sup>, with full 15–17 decimal digits precision.

So you're fine.